# ¿Cómo añadir cabecera CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) en un bus de servicio de Oracle (OSB?)

Tags: ajax, webservice, phonegap

Estoy trabajando con unos servicios web desplegados en un OSB, los clientes que los consumen son una pagina web construida en .net y una aplicación móvil hecha en phonegap, la petición desde el cliente ajax hacia el servidor funciona, incluso el servidor retorna los datos correctamente, pero el problema es que en el navegador los datos se bloquean por ende no se muestran y sale este error: "Error falta cabacera Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ", investigando un poco, pude observar que es necesario configurar en el servidor CORS para que este permita las solicitudes desde cualquier dominio. 
¿Como puedo configurar esto en OSB? o ¿Se puede configurar desde ajax?

Comment: quiza este post te ayude https://ofmcanberra.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-osb/

Comment: Ya lo había hecho y no funcionó